# How to understand `org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.0 -> 5.0.3 (*)` in `gradle dependencies`?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, version

When I run `gradle dependencies` on a project, it shows the dependency tree, and some of them are looking like:

```
+--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3

+--- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:1.8.1
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.1.2
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.0 -> 5.0.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:4.0 -> 5.0.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0 -> 5.0.3
```

For the last 3 lines, each line has two versions, `4.0` and `5.0.3`.

What information can I get from this line? Does it mean the `rest-assured 1.8.1` was relied on `4.0`, but now it found a new version `5.0.3` existed, so it just use the new version?

Is it safe to use it this way? Is it better to upgrade the `rest-assured` to a new version which replied on ASM `5.0.3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952388/what-does-arrow-mean-in-gradles-dependency-graph/27952415#27952415) answer.

**explanation**

It means that among dependencies there are *conflicted* - with same group and artifactId. They are often transitively downloaded with dependencies specified. Gradle tries to resolve it automatically - by picking the latest version (signed with `->`). Conflicting dependencies can be excluded.