# Where can I find the document for `(*)` and `1.7.6 -> 1.7.7` in the output of `gradle dependencies`

Tags: gradle, dependencies

For a gradle project with simple `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories.jcenter()

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.5.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1'
}
```

When I run `gradle dependencies`, it will show:

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.5.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.1.5.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.1.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.1.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.1.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.1.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2
|    |    |         +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.13
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.1.5.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.54
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.54
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:7.0.54
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.3
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.3
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.1.GA
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.6.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1 -> 1.7.7
```

There are two things I'm not very sure, although I've read some articles:

1. `(*)` means this dependency is already present and download in previous steps
2. `1.7.1 -> 1.7.7` this dependency is declared as `1.7.1`, but gradle decide to use `1.7.7` after conflict resolution

Not sure if my understanding correct, how can I find some official document to explain them? I searched the gradle website, but not find yet

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952388/what-does-arrow-mean-in-gradles-dependency-graph/27952415#27952415 Unfortunately don't know where are the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not an official documentation, I found the following in gradle [**dependency-resolution-reporting.md**](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/9a94ed7396103eb9062041e4e66acd15b88334d3/design-docs/dependency-resolution-reporting.md) design-doc:

> - avoid regression of current features:
>
>   - subtree is omitted (*)

Note, however, that this design-doc was changed on April 2 (see change [**here**](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/0a9b8fb25c191e1f8cfa97b5ddc80a02673200b1)) as part of the work on the release of v2.5 and this comment was removed from this document.