# Why org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.4 depends on two versions of mockito-core?

Tags: gradle, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am getting the following error during the run of Junit tests.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor

    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The reason I found while searching was that there might be multiple versions of mockito being used and it seems to be true.

```
gradle :commons:dependencies | grep mock
```

returns following

```
\--- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.4
     +--- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:1.7.4
     |    +--- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:1.7.4
     |    |    +--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.7.4
     |    |    \--- org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.4
     |    |         +--- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:1.7.4 (*)
     |    |         \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9 (*)
     |    \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9 (*)
     \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19 -> 2.8.9 (*)
```

Why powermock 1.7.4 is recursively depending on mockito 1.10.19 and 2.8.9?

Answer (score 0):

`org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.4` is compiled against mockito version `1.10.19`
[(1)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.4)

`org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:1.7.4` is compiled against both `1.10.19` and `2.8.9` and provides a dependency of `mockito-core` [(2)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito-common/1.7.4)

`org.powermock:powermock-core:1.7.4` is compiled against `2.8.9`
[(3)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.7.4)

There is an update path from mockito-core version `1.10.19` to the recent version (currently `3.2.4`).

Gradle discovers that there is a conflict and the minimum required version is `2.8.9`.
Thats what you see in the output. (Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916424/where-can-i-find-the-document-for-and-1-7-6-1-7-7-in-the-output-of-g) can help you understand the syntax.)

---

PowerMock `1.7.x` requires a mockito version of at least `2.8.9` [(4)](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito)

However using `Mockito 2.8.9` together with powermock requires you to use `powermock-api-mockito2`, so change that in your gradle config. [(5)](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/819)