# Why did a specific jar file get included?

Tags: gradle

I have a project that uses gradle and `mavenCentral()` (plus `mavenLocal()`). It has enough dependencies that I can't go through them one by one.

Given the name of a .jar file in `build/install/x/lib`, how do I find out the chain of transitive dependencies that caused it to be included?

*update*: I discovered `gradle dependencies`. The output shows:

```
org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:2.1.1
   \---- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.1.3
```

What does this mean? 1.1.1 is the version I expect, and 1.1.3 is the version I seem to actually end up using. Looking at [the pom for commons-jexl](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-jexl/2.1.1/commons-jexl-2.1.1.pom) it looks like it does indeed list logging:1.1.1 as a requirement. What's going on? Is there a way for me to tell it to avoid certain versions, or force it to use the version it was set to?

The problem in my case is that it's including a -SNAPSHOT version and I'd rather it didn't. In fact I probably want it to just use the version numbers I'm asking for instead of the most recent it can find.

Comment: The [dependencies documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html) a good summary (see the user guide for a longer walkthrough). Another dependency is forcing a upgrade resolution, but you might be able to use an exclude rule or [resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to avoid that.

Comment: @redtuna, is that clear now for you or you still need any explanation?

Comment: @Opal I wouldn't quite say that it's clear. What it looks like is that this isn't exactly gradle's doing, perhaps the commons-jexl maven file says to use the latest available commons-logging. Now I need to also become an expert at maven. Or perhaps it's something in the gradle configuration, I don't know. The thing is Turing-complete after all.

Comment: @redtuna, see my response. Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies of gradle-managed project have their own dependencies (they're called *transitive*). It may happen (and happens quite often) that two different dependencies has the same (group and module) dependency but in the different version). This is the case with `commons-logging:commons-logging`. In this case there are two transitive dependencies one versioned with `1.1.1` and the second one with `1.1.3`. If both of the libraries will be included in the final artifact it may result in a conflict and exception. To prevent such situation gradle tries to resolve mentioned version resolution problems by picking (by default) the *latest* version. It's indicated with the right arrow `->` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952388/what-does-arrow-mean-in-gradles-dependency-graph). You can exclude transitive dependencies from a particular dependency. [This](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) chapter of manual might be useful.

Comment: Thanks! With this I was able to figure things out. It turns out no dependency was asking for that number directly, but one dependency was asking for "the highest available number", and that showed up in the gradle dependencies output.