# Unable to sync gradle build when trying to use Espresso 2

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I've just migrated my androidproject from Eclipse to Android Studio and Gradle. Now I'm trying to migrate from using a separate testproject to using Gradle and Espresso 2, but I keep running into the same problem. My build wont complete when I've added the espresso2 dependencies. I keep getting the samme error message:

[image: eror]

Can anyone point me to the solution for this problem. I've searched for a solution for two days already and nothing works.

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    // Testing-only dependencies
    // Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.
    androidTestCompile  'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    // Android JUnit Runner
    androidTestCompile  'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    // JUnit4 Rules
    androidTestCompile  'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    // Espresso core
    androidTestCompile  'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    // Espresso-contrib for DatePicker, RecyclerView, Drawer actions,     Accessibility checks, CountingIdlingResource
    androidTestCompile  'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile  'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}
```

More info on error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration     ':app:_debugAndroidTestCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
Required by: appName:app:unspecified >     com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.1
> Could not parse POM        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom
> Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Running: "..\gradlew -q dependencies appName:dependencies --configuration androidTestCompile --stacktrace"

```
20:43:24.539 [DEBUG]             [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.ResolvedConfigurationDependencyGraphVisitorourceResolver.java:391)
at     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$2.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:237)
at    org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAc cess.java:308)
at    org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(D efaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
at        org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunning Operation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
at    org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunn ingOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModule ComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:63)
at    org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRe pository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:284)
at    org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:38)
at     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:70)
at    org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:114)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:97)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:70)
... 98 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:     file:/C:/Users/Thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-    2.1/com.squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/96cec80cd552
3edeb350e3aaede11430cef7be55/javawriter-2.1.1.pom; lineNumber: 2;     columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
at   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.parseToDom(PomReader.java:191)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader$1.transform(PomReader.java:98)
... 125 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the right dependency - doh. As I said Gradle newbie.

```
dependencies {

...

androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put the same in Android.mk file? If so can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952388/what-does-arrow-mean-in-gradles-dependency-graph). It contains gradle command to list the dependencies for androidTestCompile configuration like that: `./gradlew -q dependencies your_app:dependencies --configuration androidTestCompile`, which will probably show you dependency conflicts.