# How to understand the output of command 'gradle dependencies'?

Tags: gradle, tree, dependencies, output

There is part of the output:

[output of gradle dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pudy4.png)

What does the symbols ('+','\','->','()','(*)') exactly mean?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`+`, `-`, `|` and `\` are just used to draw the tree - it's a kind of [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

When it comes to `(*)` and `->` please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952388/what-does-arrow-mean-in-gradles-dependency-graph) question and answer.

---

#### TL;DR

`(*)` - is used to indicate that particular dependency is described somewhere else in the tree

`->`  - is used to point the dependency that *wins* in version conflict.

Comment: I see some files list directly under one another. Yet one has a '+' sign and the one below it has a '\'. There is no indent, they're directly ontop of each other. What is the meaning of the '+' vs the '\', why wouldn't it show two '+' or two '\'? is there a greater meaning?

Comment: So as @opal mentioned, it's kind of ASCII art to represent tree. + and \ both shows node but \ suggests last node of that series.