# Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have following dependency and getting `CoordinatorLayout$Behavior` duplicate entry. I have searched so more but did not find any solution.

I am getting

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]
at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
... 50 more
```

where core UI comes in? I think this makes issues. Can anyone know where i need to exclude one of this lib?

I have explore my all lib and having following scene.

[image]

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.0@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.github.travijuu:numberpicker:1.0.7'
compile 'com.github.carlosmuvi:SegmentedProgressBar:0.6.0'
compile 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:0.3.0'
compile 'com.bogdwellers:pinchtozoom:0.1'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
compile files('libs/PGSDK_V2.1.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.race604.waveloading:library:1.1.1'
compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
compile 'com.msg91.sendotp.library:library:3.1'
}
```

Comment: We had similar issue with Duplicate zip entry in Android support library. It could be because some libraries you referenced are with newer version of support library. This newer version support library's class conflicts with older version support related libraries. E.g. Move CoordinatorLayout class from one library (design) to another (core-ui).
We resolve this problem by upgrading all related support libraries in build.gradle.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I just did it like. It's working now

**Solution 1**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
```

**Solution 2 (NEW)**

Migrate your code to AndroidX

[image]

Comment: awesome Bhavesh bhai... Thanks, It's a working solution

Comment: still 27.1.0 is not available

Comment: you saved our life and time. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Aside of using `Project` view -> `External Libraries`, I use `gradle` command to output the dependencies into a txt file for searching.  Use `./gradlew` On Mac and `gradlew.bat` on Window.

```
$ ./gradlew -q :app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

In `dependencies.txt`, use "Find" and type "design", for example, and look at all highlighted libraries and their version number.  From some SO posts, they suggest to exclude duplicated dependencies.  If a dependency is included by another one (for example, `com.android.support:cardview-v7` is included by `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth`), we can omit that dependency from the app/build.gradle.

I fixed my project by removing these dependencies from my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
```

I keep this one (and upgrade from 27.0.2 to 27.1.0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Add exclude to following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2', {
    exclude group: 'android.arch.lifecycle', module: 'extensions'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-ui'
}
```

I got into the lifecycle issue after add/remove dependencies.  Another SO post suggest that two different version of library was included.  So, I updated the output file in step 1 and check:

```
+--- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
|    +--- 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0' 

+--- 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'
|    +--- 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
```

By excluding `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` that solve the compile problem.

Comment: Or instead of excluding, use the Firebase UI version that aligns with the Firebase version... https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Answer (score 5):

Run this to view app dependencies

```
gradlew -q :app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

It will output a big tree, where:

- **(*)** is used to indicate that particular dependency is described somewhere else in the tree
- **->** (arrow) is used to point the dependency that *wins* in version conflict. By default, gradle chooses the newest version.

Output:

```
+--- com.android.support:design:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:26.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*)
```

In my case I found that `com.android.support:design:26.1.0` was depending on `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)`, which resolved to 27.1.1 instead of 26.1.0

**Solution**
Force version 26.1.0 by declaring in gradle `compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0") { force = true }`

**References**

- [How to understand the output of command 'gradle dependencies'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136789/how-to-understand-the-output-of-command-gradle-dependencies)
- [Gradle: how to display where a dependency conflict arises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311727/gradle-how-to-display-where-a-dependency-conflict-arises)
- [Understanding and dominating gradle dependencies](https://www.devsbedevin.com/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/)

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
```

Comment: you can fix the issue like this

Comment: While your answer may be correct, you should explain why you came up with this solution. Also your comment should be edited into the answer.