# about duplicate.zip entry

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

my error is
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\grand\AndroidStudioProjects\IbzChatApp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\grand.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\f6b3408b9edbc135d6bc5477270b0eb4\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))"

My project gradle is:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven
                {
                    url "https://maven.google.com"
                }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my app gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.grand.lapitchat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### These are my stack-trace results:

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\grand\AndroidStudioProjects\IbzChatApp\app\google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\grand\AndroidStudioProjects\IbzChatApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\grand\IbzChatApp\ChatActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\grand\AndroidStudioProjects\IbzChatApp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\grand\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\f6b3408b9edbc135d6bc5477270b0eb4\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:`enter code here`
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\grand\AndroidStudioProjects\IbzChatApp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\grand\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\f6b3408b9edbc135d6bc5477270b0eb4\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\grand\AndroidStudioProjects\IbzChatApp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\grand\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\f6b3408b9edbc135d6bc5477270b0eb4\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.shrinkWithProguard(MainDexListTransform.java:232)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:184)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\grand\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\f6b3408b9edbc135d6bc5477270b0eb4\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
    ... 50 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

20 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 16 up-to-date
```

I have been trying all sorts of things to fix this, many of the other answers haven't helped me at all. Please can someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate zip entry \[classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044782/duplicate-zip-entry-classes-jarandroid-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.
i updated support dependencies 
where:
    `compile 'com.android.support:xxx:27.0.2'` 
to:
     `compile 'com.android.support:xxx:27.1.0'`

and

`buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'` 
to: 
`buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'`

and problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and none of the solutions above worked for me. So I deleted my `.gradle` and `build` folders in my application directory then went into the `app` folder and deleted the second `build` folder, cleaned the project, rebuilt it and the error was gone.