# Duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a signed APK, but an error will appear at the end:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://github.com/omadahealth/omada-nexus/raw/master/release" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {


    }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {

        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myandroidapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            //shrinkResources false
            //minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //debuggable false
            //jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            //zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            //debuggable true
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            //minifyEnabled false
            //shrinkResources false
            //renderscriptDebuggable false
            //jniDebuggable false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/**'
        exclude 'META-INF/**'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

}

android {
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Navigation Drawer Library
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //Google, Inc (Play services) Libraries
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:11.8.0'
    //Google, Inc (Firebase) Libraries
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    // Google, Inc (Support) Libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    // Facebook, Inc SDKs
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    // Libraries for images
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-twitter:0.5.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    // Location Helper Library
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
    // Time library
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    // Others
    // event bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.3'
    implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.3'
    implementation 'com.greysonparrelli.permiso:permiso:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.5.2'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Remove JAR files from your libs folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate zip entry \[classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044782/duplicate-zip-entry-classes-jarandroid-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout)

Answer (score 13):

This may be due to different versions of the support library being used. 
Add the following in your build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
       force 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
       force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
       force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
   }
}
```