# Duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class

Tags: android

I tried to debug my application, but an error appeared:

> Cause: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class

I found why that is incorrect from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496941/duplicate-entry-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout), but I can't find where I am using a different `support:appcompat-v7`.

This is my **External Libraries**:

[image]

And **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //support
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["databinding"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["databinding-adapters"]
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["support-v4"]) {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["appcompat-v7"]) {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["design"]) {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["annotations"]
    //rx
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxjava2"]
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxandroid2"]) {
        exclude module: 'rxjava'
    }
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxcache2"]) {
        exclude module: 'rxjava'
        exclude module: 'dagger'
    }

    //network
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["retrofit"]) {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
        exclude module: 'okio'
    }

    compile files('libs/fastjson-converter-1.0.jar')
    compile(name:'pulltorefresh-1.1', ext:'aar')

    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["retrofit-adapter-rxjava2"]) {
        exclude module: 'rxjava'
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
        exclude module: 'retrofit'
        exclude module: 'okio'
    }
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["okhttp3"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["okhttp-logging-interceptor"]

    //tools
    provided rootProject.ext.dependencies["javax.annotation"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["dagger2"]
    annotationProcessor(rootProject.ext.dependencies["dagger2-compiler"]) {
        exclude module: 'dagger'
    }
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["androideventbus"]
//    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["timber"]
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["greendao"]
//    compile (rootProject.ext.dependencies["fastjson"])
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["gson"])
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["retrofit-converter-gson"])
    compile(rootProject.ext.dependencies["MPAndroidChart"])


    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["glide"]
    annotationProcessor(rootProject.ext.dependencies["glide-compiler"])
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxlifecycle2"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxlifecycle2-android"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxlifecycle2-components"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxpermissions2"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxbinding2"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxbinding2-support-v4"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxbinding2-appcompat-v7"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxbinding2-design"]
    compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["rxbinding2-recyclerview-v7"]

    //test
    testCompile rootProject.ext.dependencies["junit"]
}
```

version:

```
ext {

    android = [
            compileSdkVersion: 26,
            buildToolsVersion: "26.0.2",

            minSdkVersion    : 15,
            targetSdkVersion : 26,
            versionCode      : 2,
            versionName      : "2.5"
    ]

    version = [
            androidSupportSdkVersion: "26.0.2",
            databindingVersion      : "1.3.3",
            retrofitSdkVersion      : "2.3.0",
            dagger2SdkVersion       : "2.11",
            glideSdkVersion         : "4.3.1",
            butterknifeSdkVersion   : "8.8.1",
            rxlifecycleSdkVersion   : "1.0",
            rxlifecycle2SdkVersion  : "2.2.0",
            espressoSdkVersion      : "2.2.2",
            canarySdkVersion        : "1.5.1",
            rxbinding2              : "2.0.0"
    ]
}
```

I don't know where `'27.1.1'` comes from.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509295/2196176

Comment: @Sunny It's save me ! thanks ~ but I want to know where `'27.1.1'` comes from.

Comment: Maybe you are using any third party library and it has the dependency on 27.1.1.