# Latest google maps library uses old version of support library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-maps-android-api-2

I recently changed my build.gradle files to use `implementation` instead of `compile`.
The `implementation` keyword forces you to make sure that all of your dependencies are with the same version.

Apperantly the google maps dependency `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'` is using an older version of the support library (26.1.0)

I was able to diagnose the issue after running `./gradlew dependencies -b app/build.gradle`

Here is the output:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
```

**The question is:** is there a solution to this situation? I know that using `compile` instead of `implementation` solves the problem, but `compile` will be removed in 2019.

Here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You can restrict the support lib version try to use `resolutionStrategy` Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/49596276/4168607 or similar.

Comment: "I know that using compile instead of implementation solves the problem" -- not that I am aware of. Add `implementation` for `support-v4` for `27.1.0` to force the upgrade of that artifact. Then, hope that Google not only updates their libraries, but also uses smaller/less-obsolete artifacts than `support-v4`.

Comment: Use ***'api'*** when you face such a situation here is the better explanation https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa