# Getting Error on Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Actually I'm adding the multiDexEnabled true and also adding the compile

> 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' again I'm getting the same error

Error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Comment: Too old question. Search on Google.

Comment: multiDexEnabled true added. but when I'm running the app getting the Error

Comment: Try to Clean and rebuild the project

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49596276/568898

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 3.0 and above add below to app.gradle:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Eg:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //Add this
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @ss. already I'm Added but getting the Same Error

Answer (score 0):

If you add below dependency into app level gradle file then..

dependencies {
   'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

then you make application level class like below ..

```
public class YourApllication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
  }
}
```

and this class pass into andriod manifest file in application tag.

```
        android:name="YourApllication"
```