# duplicate zip entry CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]) and unable to merge Dex after updating libraries

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am using same version of libraries and as per firebaseui documentation for 15.0.0 version of Firebase/Play Services corresponding firebaseui version is 3.3.1.It seems that it is because of some transitive dependency.I tried to resolve it by adding implementation keyword for specific dependencies but unable to resolve this problem.

build.gradle file for my project.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    compile 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-core:4.0.8'
    compile 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-ui:4.0.8'
    compile 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-adapter:4.0.8'
    compile 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-file-storage:4.0.8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    compile 'co.chatsdk.chatsdk:chat-sdk-firebase-push:4.0.8'
    compile 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:4.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

2 warnings that I am getting in build.gradle are

[image]

[image]

I tried to resolve this by adding implementation declarations. How this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate zip entry \[classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044782/duplicate-zip-entry-classes-jarandroid-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout)

Answer (score 0):

[Google recently starting breaking up Firebase and Google Play Services](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html).
In doing so, they seem to have pushed a `15.0.2` version of one of the Firebase libraries as a dependency on the other libraries, even if you're asking for `15.0.0`, leading to the conflict you're seeing.

Their instructions didn't seem to work for us when we tried to update based on that blog post, so for now we reverted to Google Play Services 12.0.1 and Firebase 12.0.1 until Google fixes this issue on their end.